# Why do I get "Segmentation fault" while running git clone?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, git

I'm getting a segfault while cloning a Github repository:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd spotify/
pi@raspberrypi:~/spotify $ git clone https://github.com/Fornoth/spotify-connect-web.git
Segmentation fault
pi@raspberrypi:~/spotify $
```

Any ideas what's wrong? I use the latest Raspbian with standard repo. Git version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/spotify $ git --version
git version 2.1.4
```

Comment: running out of space or memory/swap?

Comment: I don't think so, I have 25 gigs of disk space left and use ~100 MB of RAM.

Comment: Could you edit your post and cut&paste the command you issue and the result.  If it is the above then your version of the git program is probably corrupt.  Are you using non-Raspbian repositories?

Comment: I edited the post. I use only deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

Comment: You have corruption.  I just ran the git clone on a Pi2 and it took a few seconds to complete (also git version 2.14).  You could try to reinstall git (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall git`) but who can guess at the extent of any corruption.

Comment: Oh, reinstall actually helped. Thanks Joan, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segmentation fault is a strong indicator of SD card corruption, program corruption, or using software from incompatible repositories.

You could try re-installing the software.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall git`

Be aware that if you have SD card corruption you may just be [papering over the cracks](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paper+over+the+cracks).